# Why does my lead-function generate NA values?

Tags: r, lead

I have had to construct a reference table to keep track of what amount of academic credits our students should have taken given the current date. I have one row per admissionround and course.

I want to code a *finished*-variable that takes the value 1 for the last course for each admissionround and 0 for every other value (this will let me deal with students who should have finished their programmes already).

I write

```
ekon_program<-ekon_program%>%mutate(finished=ifelse(lead(kull)=kull,0,1))
```

Where *kull* is my admissionround variable, which will change by +1 in the row directly succeding the last course of the current admissionround.  Strangely enough, the last course for each admissionround is now coded as "NA", but all other values are coded as 0.

I could easily correct this by converting all NA-values to 1, but why is this happening in the first place?

Excerpt of data:

```
ekon_program <- structure(list(sd = structure(c(17042, 17042, 17042, 17042, 17042, 
17042, 17042, 17042, 17042, 17042, 17042, 17042, 17042, 17042, 
17406, 17406, 17406, 17406, 17406, 17406), class = "Date"), points_ekon = c(15, 
15, 15, 15, 7.5, 7.5, 15, 7.5, 7.5, 15, 15, 15, 30, 0, 15, 15, 
15, 15, 7.5, 7.5), summer_break_ekon = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1), weeks_course = c(10, 
10, 10, 10, 5, 5, 10, 5, 5, 10, 10, 10, 20, 0, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
5, 5), points_expected = c(0, 15, 30, 45, 60, 67.5, 75, 90, 97.5, 
105, 120, 135, 150, 180, 0, 15, 30, 45, 60, 67.5), order = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L), starttermin = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), kull = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), start_date = structure(c(17041, 
17041, 17041, 17041, 17041, 17041, 17041, 17041, 17041, 17041, 
17041, 17041, 17041, 17041, 17405, 17405, 17405, 17405, 17405, 
17405), class = "Date"), start_date_points = structure(c(17041, 
17132, 17202, 17272, 17342, 17461, 17496, 17566, 17601, 17636, 
17706, 17860, 17930, 18070, 17405, 17496, 17566, 17636, 17706, 
17825), class = "Date"), end_date_points = structure(c(17131, 
17201, 17271, 17341, 17460, 17495, 17565, 17600, 17635, 17705, 
17859, 17929, 18069, 18069, 17495, 17565, 17635, 17705, 17824, 
17859), class = "Date"), finished_date = structure(c(18070, 18070, 
18070, 18070, 18070, 18070, 18070, 18070, 18070, 18070, 18070, 
18070, 18070, 18070, 18434, 18434, 18434, 18434, 18434, 18434
), class = "Date")), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -20L), groups = structure(list(
    start_date = structure(c(17041, 17405), class = "Date"), 
    .rows = list(1:14, 15:20)), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One issue is that `=` is not `==`, secondly, `lead` by `default` creates a `NA` at the end, if we need to change, change the `default`.  Also, we don't need `ifelse` to coerce, it can be done with `as.integer`

```
library(dplyr)
ekon_program %>%
   mutate(finished = as.integer(lead(kull, default = last(kull)) != kull))
```

Comment: If I interpret this answer correctly  the lead function will (for some unknown reason) consider the last value in a group (admissionround in this case) as NA unless otherwise specified? I don't understand the meaning of this rule but it "does" seem to work when I set default to 0 instead.

Comment: @Magnus  `lead(1:5)#[1]  2  3  4  5 NA`  The last value is by `default = NA`  I changed the `NA` to another value because `==` returns `NA` when there is a comparison with `NA` i.e. `NA==2`

Comment: Sure, if the lead value does not exist (such as the lead value to 5 in 1:5) I could understand that but....now we really "have" lead values in the very next group?

I'm marking this as the correct answer, thank you for your time!

Comment: @Magnus If you need this to be used within each group, you need a `group_by` before applying tat.  The lead will remove the first observation and move the values while the `lag` does the reverse